# Shouldn't the removal of an answer be visible in the timeline for everyone?

Tags: feature-request, revision-history

Background: I commented on a possibly dangerous command in an answer to

https://askubuntu.com/questions/310358/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-trying-to-use-chmod/310364#310364

The answer was removed subsequently - Now I was curious and looked into the time line (https://askubuntu.com/posts/310358/timeline) - and found no trace
[image]

Comment: Which timeline are you looking at? I see it in mine.

Comment: @Seth: http://askubuntu.com/posts/310358/timeline

Comment: @Seth you are a mod, for anyone else (10kers included) it doesn't appear.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I think is because you don't have 10k

Comment: @Braiam I realize I'm a mod, but you don't even see it?

Comment: @Seth nope. Nothing.

Comment: @guntbert is this a feature requests?

Comment: @Braiam good idea, tagging it.